# Bash: replace empty line with string

Tags: bash

How to replace blank line in text file, let's say that file is:

```
first

third
```

with some string( for ex. "second" ) using Bash?
I wanna make sth. like this:

```
first
second
third
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed -i -e 's/^$/second/' file
```

The `-i` option toggles the in-place replacement.

Comment: Exactly, that seems to be the easiest option!

Comment: also `-i.bak` will keep a backup of the original incase something is wrong

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a [default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) for an unset or empty variable:

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
   echo "${line:-second}"  # empty lines are default to 'second'
done > file.out
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[ -z "$line" ]` to test if your `line` is empty and do whatever you want with it.

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
   if [ -z "$line" ]
   then
     //$line is empty
   fi
done
```

EDIT -- if you want to replace the empty line with "second" -- so you will end up with `file.out` which is the new file with empty lines replaced with `second`

```
touch file.out
cat file.txt | while read line
do
       if [ -z "$line" ]
       then
         echo "second" >> file.out
       else
          echo $line >> file.out
       fi
 done
```

Comment: i think he needs to know the `do whatever`. Because he has asked `How to replace blank line`

Comment: @abasu He can write `echo "second"` if all he wants to write `second` when a line is empty...or other things, if he is interested...

Comment: great, +1 for a simple yet elegant approach

Comment: Your scripts will throw errors unless you add a space before the "]" character.